# Direct Print RDLC report on client PC in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, printing

I have read many articles and answers here regarding this but nothing can solve my issue. That's why I am asking this question again.
I develop a Invoice App in Asp.net. I can't print invoice directly on client PC. It always ask printer preview that irritate client. I have successfully develop a code for directly printing but it only execute on local host only. 
Please help me and suggest me what to do as soon as possible.
In Javascript or ASP.NET or something else that can help me.

Comment: What format is the invoice? PDF? HTML? DOCX?

Comment: i am generating rdlc report from MS SQL data

Comment: yeah, you did say that, sorry, I'm not 100% familiar with how RDLC works client side

Comment: oh. if you can guide me any concept in java script or asp.net that can print part of page directly on default printer of client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use SSRS and generate the report in pdf format on the server. Sending it to the client, we send it with a mime-type:`application/x-xyz-printpdf` - you also have to set the content-disposition: with **filename** and I can't recall if **inline** or **attachment** value, so that the browser will behave and not simply download and save the file, but will kick off the associated program

the client has a slightly modified version of SumatraPDF, which is associated with `application/x-xyz-printpdf` in the registry (windows clients only - there's ways to do this in other OS's but all our clients run Windows, so we've never bothered)

This modified sumatraPDF never displays the document, all it does is display a print dialog with the previously selected printer for the report selected. This is so, invoices will default to one printer, other reports to a different printer, it's more of a convenience (and emulates our old non-web-based application)

I am in the process of rewriting the report printing subsystem, using a substantially modified version of PDFjs and blobs, but that's in early development so I can't tell you anything about that, except that it looks like it'll work well, without the need for an external program.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds good so i will try to implement it. I will back to you with result

Comment: The hardest part is the sumatraPDF modifications - however, you can set the registry values such that it calls sumatraPDF (or any other pdf program) with the correct combinations of parameters to print immediately - the only reason I modified sumatraPDF was to get it to remember where each report was last printed

Comment: i need to install Sumatra PDF on client PC?

Comment: doesn't have to be sumatraPDF - I use sumatraPDF because it's open source and I could make the mods I needed - but yes, for my current system, an application has to be installed to handle it - the new system should be free of this annoyance, and be cross browser/cross operating system